# Table view scrolling event

Tags: ipad, uitableview

Is there any event in table view which will get triggered when i try to scroll the table view.
I want to create a down arrow image to the bottom of the table view ,when the user tries to scroll through the table view.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i recall, since UITableView Inherits from UIScroll view you can listen to  the UIScrollViewDelegate methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{


}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{


}
```

Any way. make sure that

```
tableView.delegate=self;
```

Comment: is there any way to check which is the current row which is been added to the able view

Comment: Hi @Christina 1. you can edit your comments, no need to open new one:). 2. please explain - is that an other question ?

Comment: probably yes ,See my new question and please help me ,link to the new que is:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288588/logic-for-adding-images-and-scroll-icon-to-the-table-view