# Logic for adding images and scroll icon to the table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a table view, and I am adding four `UIImageView`s to a row, so in total I have five rows and twenty image views. I am inserting images one by one into the cell. The second row will only start to fill once all four image views are filled.

I need some logic for this. I mean, how can I check which place is next to be filled in the table view and at which event? How can I add images one by one to the `UIImageView`s? Also, initially only two rows will be shown. After filling these two rows, when images begin to enter into the third row, I need to show an icon adjacent to the last row that is on the screen, to tell the user that there is more data below. Also, is there any event to detect which row is currently the last row on screen?

Also is there any way to individually select the images from a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code:-

```
.h file code


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface helpTableViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *gridTableView;
    NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
    int widthview,widthview1;

    }
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITableView *gridTableView;
-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)crossViewButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

.m file code:-

```
@synthesize gridTableView;
@synthesize imagesArray;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.imagesArray=tempArray;
    [tempArray release];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic5.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic6.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"]];
    [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"]];
    widthview=0;
    widthview1=0;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.gridTableView=nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [imagesArray release];
    [gridTableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell=nil;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =[self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];

    }

            return cell;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
        scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];       
        for (int i=0; i<4;i++) {        
            UIView *profileView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(widthview+10, 12, 95, 155)];
            profileView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            UIImageView *profileimageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 8, 83, 106)];
            [profileimageView setImage:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            profileimageView.tag=i+90;
            [profileView addSubview:profileimageView];
            [profileimageView release];
            [scrollView addSubview:profileView];
            widthview=widthview+105;
            NSLog(@"%d",widthview);
        }
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(widthview1+10, 12, 95, 155)];
        //button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        button.tag=999999;
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:button];
        widthview=widthview+105;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthview, 180);

    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
        scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];       
        for (int i=0; i<4;i++) {        
            UIView *profileView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(widthview1+10, 12, 95, 155)];
            profileView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

            UIImageView *profileimageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 8, 83, 106)];
            //  [profileimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gridimage1.png"]];
            profileimageView.tag=4+i;
            [profileimageView setImage:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:3+i]];
            [profileView addSubview:profileimageView];

            [scrollView addSubview:profileView];
            [profileimageView release];
            widthview1=widthview1+105;
            NSLog(@"%d",widthview1);
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthview1, 180);

    }return cell;

}

// Override to support row selection in the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark button methods


-(void)imageButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.imagesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abdulprofilepic.png"]];
    [self.gridTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Friend my app is crashing with this code when i click on the button

Comment: can u tell me what should be the button name.sorry i am a fresher in this thats y asking

Comment: i cant see anythigng on my screen ,neither the tabke view nor the button

Comment: have you put a table view inside your view,add make table row height to 180. den try

Comment: crash might be due to self.images array.This is array that contains images.Make your array add images in it.

Comment: NSMutableArray *array;[array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"]];
 [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"]];
 [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.png"]];
 [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image4.png"]];
 [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image5.png"]];

Comment: Shall i copy paste the whole thing i mean in new project

Comment: and do i have to add table view using nib file

Comment: yes dear you have to add table view in xib and made connection to fileowner after that put some images in your project and then add those images in array.

Comment: i added the table view and saved it but still the file owner is not showing the name of the table view

Comment: its showing 25 errors saying table vie wnot declared ,,array not declared

Answer (score 1):

You should keep all of the logic (and data) in your table view controller (`UITableViewController` subclass). I suggest you have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass that can hold 4 images (the cell itself should be responsible for the layout), and the table view controller is responsible for setting it up. In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can look at your collection of images, then just use [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to figure out which images should be in the cell for that particular index path.

As for individually selecting images, perhaps you could have your cells know their index path (set as a custom property in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`), then each have a delegate method telling your controller that a certain image was pressed (for example, `-cellAtIndexPath:didSelectImageAtIndex:`).

Answer (score 1):

try this,
As there are fix number of images that you want to show in your row i. e. 4
So what you have to do is:-
in .h file

```
int widthview,widthview1;
```

in .m file in viewdidload

```
   widthview=0;
    widthview1=0;



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;//to remove blu selection color
    return cell;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
        scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];       
        for (int i=0; i<4;i++) {        
            UIImageView *profileimageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(widthview+10, 12, 95, 155)];
            [profileimageView setImage:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            [profileimageView release];
            [scrollView addSubview:profileimageView];
            widthview=widthview+105;
            NSLog(@"%d",widthview);
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthview, 180);

    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
        scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];       
        for (int i=0; i<4;i++) {        
            UIImageView *profileimageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(widthview+10, 12, 95, 155)];
            [profileimageView setImage:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:4+i]];
            [profileimageView release];
            [scrollView addSubview:profileimageView];
            widthview1=widthview1+105;
            NSLog(@"%d",widthview1);
    }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthview1, 180);

    }
return cell;

}
```

This code is for 2 rows do the same thing for next three rows.
Adjust the coordinates according to your requirement.
hope this will save your time.

Comment: will this code help me to add images one by one..to image view in cells

Comment: @Christina yes it will try this I have also used this code to add images in scroll view in table view cell

Comment: once i try this i will inform you ok,,but i want to add images in click of a button like when i click on it once then first image is isplayed on thetable view ,then iagain i click on the button then next image is displayed and so on.how can i achieve this ,were to call which events

Comment: @christina where are your buttons

Comment: @christina can you tell the exact scenario what you want to do.

Comment: ya sure ,see i have a table view lets say blank initially.Now i have 4 image view on one row of cell and then i have a button.now what i want is when i click the button then first image in my array is to be placed in the first image view ,then on again clicking the image will be setted to next image view and so on.after filling all 4 image view in first row then any new images are added to second row first view.Please give me some clue.that how to add anything to table view everytime .

Answer (score 0):

answer for Also is there any way to individually select the images from a row? :
Give image to button and add that button inside row!!